# Can someone identity this succulent pictured

Tags: succulents

This plant looks like a sedum of some kind to me and I would like to know if it is a sedum. It has hairy type tentacles rising about 10cm and has a tendancy to flop.

Comment: Nothing pictured!

Comment: @rufus thorbold welcome to G&L. Please take the tour https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour to get familiar with concept of Q&A on this site. Adding images to your post will help to identify plants and answer your question.